# Spring singletons is instantiated before JNDI DataSourceBinding occured

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, datasource, jndi

I am a newbie to Java EE, I have some issue where spring singletons which have property of a JndiObjectFactoryBean is instantiated before the JNDI itself is bound. It cause an error on deployment and make the application deployment failed.

Is there anyway to configure the priority of the initialization? Such as make the JNDI DataSourceBinding instantiated first before the spring singletons?

I am using jboss-5.1.0.GA as my application server.

Here is the snippet of the server.log:

```
2015-05-25 16:47:14,410 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (main) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1f873f7: defining beans [daoAuthenticationProvider,authenticationManager,settingbean,authenticationFailureHandler,authenticationSuccessHandler,sessionRegistry,sessionAuthenticationStrategy,authenticationFilter,sessionManageProcessingFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,filterChainProxy,securityContextPersistenceFilter,filterSecurityInterceptor,httpRequestAccessDecisionManager,roleVoter,cxcdataDS,datasourceByJNDI,JTATransactionManager,jdbcTXManager,jdbcTemplate,jdbcTemplateext]; root of factory hierarchy
2015-05-25 16:47:14,593 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (main) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1f873f7: defining beans [daoAuthenticationProvider,authenticationManager,settingbean,authenticationFailureHandler,authenticationSuccessHandler,sessionRegistry,sessionAuthenticationStrategy,authenticationFilter,sessionManageProcessingFilter,httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,filterChainProxy,securityContextPersistenceFilter,filterSecurityInterceptor,httpRequestAccessDecisionManager,roleVoter,cxcdataDS,datasourceByJNDI,JTATransactionManager,jdbcTXManager,jdbcTemplate,jdbcTemplateext]; root of factory hierarchy
2015-05-25 16:47:14,593 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (main) Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoAuthenticationProvider' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/CXC_Security.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl#1437781' of type [org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl] while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl#1437781' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/CXC_Security.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cxcdataDS' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cxcdataDS' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/CXC_DataSource.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'datasourceByJNDI' while setting bean property 'targetDataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'datasourceByJNDI' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/CXC_DataSource.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: cxcdataDS not bound
...
```

and only after long stack trace of error the required JNDI binding is instantiated

```
2015-05-25 16:47:16,759 INFO  [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.ConnectionFactoryBindingService] (main) Bound ConnectionManager 'jboss.jca:service=DataSourceBinding,name=cxcdataDS' to JNDI name 'java:cxcdataDS'
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me for this.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure but, have you tried use as JNDI name `java:cxcdataDS` instead of `cxcdataDS` in your `CXC_Security.xml`?

Comment: Hi @Vartlok, thanks for trying to help. Fortunately I have found the cause of my problem. There is no problem on the JNDI naming itself, only a deployment issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the singletons is instantiated before JNDI is bound due to issue during deployment, for some reason the application is deployed to inside of a .sar folder belong to the JBoss. Because of that the application is loaded before the JNDI is instantiated.
After I move my application to the correct folder, it is running okay as before.